# Random function "returns a uniformly distributed int". Does this mean the probability of every number is the same?

Tags: algorithms, randomness

Most functions that generate random numbers are described as:

> Returns a pseudorandom, **uniformly distributed** int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

If I use it to generate a number in the range `[0..9]`, does **uniformly distributed** mean that the probability for `3` and `8` is the same?

As I understand it, if I run the function a sufficient number of times, I'll have the same number of occurrences for each number, 0 through 9.  Is this correct?

Alternatively, would we instead have a **normal distribution** where we would get more occurrences of the numbers 4, 5, and 6, as they are closer to the mean and hence have a higher probability of occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uniform distribution is when all values have the same probability. A random uniformly distributed integer in the range $0,\ldots,9$ will attain each of the values with probability $1/10$. In practice, you function is not truly random but only pseudorandom, so the probabilities won't be exactly $1/10$ but only very close to $1/10$.

Normal distribution is a probability distribution on real numbers. If we "bin" them then we get a normal distribution on the integers. If we "cap" it (there are several ways of doing this) then we get a probability distribution on a finite set of integers.

Comment: thanks, so all my assertions in the question body are correct, right? _Normal distribution is a probability distribution on real numbers._ - can you please clarify?

Comment: The normal distribution is a probability distribution (in fact, a family of probability distributions) on the real numbers. Sometimes people say "normal distribution" when they actually mean some discretization of the normal distribution.

Comment: _ If we "bin" them then we get a normal distribution on the integers. If we "cap" it_ - thanks, where can I read about `bin` and `cap` you're talking about?

Comment: Some question on this site mentioned discretized normal distribution, but I don't of any other particular source, though I imagine it's common in some circles.